# local site is automatically on https on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

I had an update on my computer ( ubuntu) and now my host that i had in local is not working anymore : 
This site can’t be reached
www.site.dev refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

This same url works on firefox and postman for my api so I am a bit lost!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just saw this post and I have my explanation.
https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/

Chrome is now redirecting all `.dev` to `https`... so I have to change my extension of local website or use another browser.

For those ones that have same issue, don't use chrome or rename your vhost and host file to another extension because `.dev` won't work chrome in `http`.

Answer (score 1):

Forcing HTTPS is a new feature of chrome. More on it [here](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/).

Apparently, it cannot be disabled. One workaround is changing your .dev domain to .test, .local or similar.

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed it and I already wrote an answer for community because I won't probably be the only one to face this.