# laravel Your connection is not private error in chrome

Tags: laravel, gmail

I am using laravel 5.4 and I updated the .env file to be as follows:

```
  MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
  MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
  MAIL_PORT=587
  MAIL_USERNAME=my gmail
  MAIL_PASSWORD=my password
  MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

when I tried to test that I got the following message

> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from test.dev (for
>   example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
>   NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

so I tried to return everything to the default but I still got the same message .. where is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [local site is automatically on https on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47716026/local-site-is-automatically-on-https-on-chrome)

Answer (score 12):

It is because your chrome version is 63. Now it is a force to use https.

If you using Valet. You may change your domain to other e.g. `.test`

The command is `valet domain test`

All your `.dev` domain will be replaced to `.test`

More info:-

https://laravel-news.com/chrome-63-now-forces-dev-domains-https

Comment: I changed mine from .dev to .php suffix. Works wonder, thanks

Answer (score 5):

change the **.dev** to **.test** into the **Homestead.yaml** and **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts**

1. *run the command* :

**vagrant reload --provision**

2. use the *"incognito window"* **Ctrl+Shift+N** or use *Internet Explorer*

Answer (score 1):

Or type: valet secure, for that project and make it secure. Worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use .dev for your local domains - the new chrome (version 63) redirects all .dev -Domains to https

Try to rename your local domains to something like lsapp.test an myfirstls.test

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem I was using Chrome version 63 and you can just downgrade to version 62 it will be fine or try using ".localhost”, “.invalid”, “.test”, or “.example” instead of ".dev"

Answer (score 0):

I received this error with Laravel 5.2 and valet. I ended up upgrading valet from v1.1.22 to v2.0.6, and using "valet secure [domain]" to secure my local dev site with a TLS certificate. I have middleware that redirects all traffic on this site to https.

Upgrading to v2 was probably not required, however my current installation broke from all the troubleshooting I attempted.